# Pytest Not Deselecting Certain Tests (but should be in pytest.ini)

Tags: python, django, pytest, pytest-django

I've got a test suite set up and have been using pytest and pytest-django.

To give some background: I am trying to do some integration testing with a headless browser and have pytest ignore certain tests that are used where I am using a standard (non-headless) browser; I'd like to deselect those tests using a real, visual browser so that they don't trigger in my CI/CD pipeline.

Given the example `pytest.ini` below, if I run `pytest launcher` it shows as I would expect that there is 1 test being deselected (the StandardBrowserTestCases class only has 1 test in it).

However, if I run `pytest other_app` (which also has a StandardBrowserTestCases class) it does not show anything being deselected and StandardBrowserTestCases is ran with the other tests and *not* deselected.

```
[pytest]
addopts =
    --nomigrations
    --cov-config=.coveragerc
    --cov=my_project
    --cov=other_app
    --cov=launcher
    --cov=people
    ; # Ignore the StandardBrowserTestCases - these are only used for local
    ; # development / visual debug and contain no real valuable tests
    --deselect=other_app/tests/test_integrations.py::StandardBrowserTestCases
    --deselect=launcher/tests/test_integrations.py::StandardBrowserTestCases
    --deselect=people/tests/test_integrations.py::StandardBrowserTestCases
    --junitxml=./test-results/junit.xml
    --cov-report html:./test-results/htmlcov
    --html=./test-results/test_results.html
    --self-contained-html
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = my_project.unit-test-settings
python_files = tests.py test_*.py *_tests.py
```

Am I using `--deselect` right? How can I figure out (troubleshoot) to see why it works on one app (`launcher`) but not the other (`other_app`)? How can I get pytest to deselect those tests from each app instead of just one?

Comment: Have you tried to use these on the command line? Does it work for the third one (`people`)? Does it work if you deselect only `launcher`? For me this looks quite ok, diffcult to say what goes wrong without the actual test layout/code.